# Max Sum Subarray - Divide and Conquer

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I created a recursive function that takes in an array of ints, and returns the sum of the continuous subarray with the largest sum.

Example:

input: 1 4 -9 8 1 3 3 1 -1 -4 -6 2 8 19 -10 -11

subarray: 8 1 3 3 1 -1 -4 -6 2 8 19

sum: 34

My algorithm is a little off. About 2/3's of my test inputs are wrong. A list of my tests is below the code.

```
def max_sum_subarray(arr, left, right):

    maxLeftBorderSum = 0
    maxRightBorderSum = 0
    leftBorderSum = 0
    rightBorderSum = 0
    center = (left + right)/2

    if left == right:
        return arr[left]

    maxLeftSum = min_sum_subarray(arr, left, center)
    maxRightSum = min_sum_subarray(arr, center+1, right)

    for i in range(center, left, -1):
        leftBorderSum = leftBorderSum + arr[i]
        if leftBorderSum > maxLeftBorderSum:
            maxLeftBorderSum = leftBorderSum

    for i in range(center+1, right):
        rightBorderSum = rightBorderSum + arr[i]
        if rightBorderSum > maxRightBorderSum:
            maxRightBorderSum = rightBorderSum  

    return max(maxLeftBorderSum + maxRightBorderSum, max(maxRightSum, maxLeftSum))
```

Some tests:

```
1 4 -9 8 1 3 3 1 -1 -4 -6 2 8 19 -10 -11
```

Correct Answer = 34
My answer = 34

```
2 9 8 6 5 -11 9 -11 7 5 -1 -8 -3 7 -2
```

Correct Answer = 30
My answer = 28

```
10 -11 -1 -9 33 -45 23 24 -1 -7 -8 19
```

Correct Answer = 50
My answer = 47

```
31 -41 59 26 -53 58 97 -93 -23 84
```

Correct Answer = 187
My answer = 187

```
3 2 1 1 -8 1 1 2 3
```

Correct Answer = 7
My answer = 4

```
12 99 99 -99 -27 0 0 0 -3 10
```

Correct Answer = 210
My answer = 198

```
-2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4
```

Correct Answer = 6
My answer = 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff)

```
#!python3
def max_sum_subarray(arr, left, right):

maxLeftBorderSum = 0
maxRightBorderSum = 0
leftBorderSum = 0
rightBorderSum = 0
center = (left + right)//2

if left == right:
    if(arr[left]>0):return arr[left]
    else:return 0

maxLeftSum = max_sum_subarray(arr, left, center)
maxRightSum = max_sum_subarray(arr, center+1, right)

for i in range(center, left-1, -1):
    leftBorderSum = leftBorderSum + arr[i]
    if leftBorderSum > maxLeftBorderSum:
        maxLeftBorderSum = leftBorderSum
for i in range(center+1, right+1):
    rightBorderSum = rightBorderSum + arr[i]
    if rightBorderSum > maxRightBorderSum:
        maxRightBorderSum = rightBorderSum  

return max(maxLeftBorderSum + maxRightBorderSum,maxRightSum, maxLeftSum)
```

- The base condition is wrong
- for loop range mistake
- calling wrong function
- if python3 use true division

Comment: What's the intuition behind going from `center` to `left`? `for i in range(center, left-1, -1): ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys 
arr = map(int,raw_input().split())
def CrossingSum(arr,l,m,h):
    summ = 0
    left_sum = -sys.maxint
    for i in range(m,l-1,-1):

            summ = summ + arr[i]
            if summ > left_sum:
                    left_sum = summ


    summ = 0
    right_sum = -sys.maxint
    for i in range(m+1,h+1):
            summ = summ + arr[i]
            if summ > right_sum:
                    right_sum = summ

    return left_sum + right_sum

def Divide(arr,l,h):
    if l ==  h :
            return arr[l]
    mid = (l+h)//2
    maximum = max(Divide(arr,l,mid) , Divide(arr,mid+1,h) , CrossingSum(arr,l,mid,h))

    return maximum

ans = Divide(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
print "ANSWER IS " , ans
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should consider that it is generally better to explain what you've done here and why.